# Getting all inputs with custom attribute in a view

Tags: sapui5

I need to go through all inputs (of different types) which contain a custom attribute in common, like below:

```
<m:Input value="{building>/shortName}" custom:required="true"/>
...
<m:Input value="{building>/longName}" custom:required="true"/>
```

So I can do a validation on each one of them.

Some of you can imagine why I'm doing that (`sap.m.Input` hasn't a `required` property itself as `sap.ui.commons.TextField` has).

By pure jQuery, I could get it, but it's definitely my last option to try.

Does anyone know how to get such filtered list of controls?

Another better solution for the same issue is also welcome.

Comment: I don't think doing validations like this is a solid way forward.. better use input validations by type binding as proposed by @aborjinik

Comment: indeed, the validations by type binding is definitely the way to go. But imagine you have a couple of required fields and don't touch on them and just click on 'Save'. It must validate them before posting, right? My need is just for that cause, not to replace the type binding.

Comment: In that case, see this blog I wrote a while ago: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/11/01/generic-sapui5-form-validator

Comment: thank you @Qualiture! that's a cleaner solution than mine and was useful for clarify my mind!

Just 2 observations though: 1) just by informing the page's ID wasn't enough, because `page.getAggregation` didn't return any control, so I had to use `view.findElements(true)` to find them. I use `semantic:FullscreenPage` instead of `Page`. 2) it doesn't update the `MessageManager` as the type binding will do by itself, which is a weird effect, because if user just type and remove the content, they will see the Message button at the bottom, but if they just click on Save, they won't. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding minLength constraint with String type and listening validation error would be a better approach.

```
<Input value="{
    path : 'building>/shortName',
    type : 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
    constraints : {
        minLength: 1
    }
}" />

sap.ui.getCore().attachValidationError(function (oEvent) {
     oEvent.getParameter("element").setValueState("Error");
});
```

Also you can have a look at this sample 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview

Comment: that would require me to call a binding validation, which is not allowed by the framework. That's why I m trying to figure out how to get all elements by a certain selector, so I can go through them. I already have a solution, that is to call view.findElements() and go through all of them checking their types, but that`s a bad approach, in my opinion.

Comment: @MarinhoBrandão can you tell me where it is written that this is not allowed by the framework? At the new version of the UI5 with MessageModel it is not even necessary to attachValidationError. It automatically shows error state if constraints fail.

Comment: hi @aborjinik, I didn't anywhere explicitly saying it, but I created an example so you can see what I mean: https://github.com/marinho/temporary-openui5-example-1

just search for XXX to see what I mean